# WordPress OAuth2 - retrieve a token in a safe way

Tags: wordpress, oauth-2.0

I have some code to generate a valid authorization token for my WordPress application, but I cannot figure out how to store it or to pass it somewhere else in a safe way.

```
require ('vendor/autoload.php');

const CLIENT_ID     = 'xxxx';
const CLIENT_SECRET = 'yyyy';
const REDIRECT_URI = '<mysite>/testRestOauth.php';
const AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT = '<myothersite>/oauth/authorize';
const TOKEN_ENDPOINT = '<myothersite>/oauth/token';

$client = new OAuth2\Client(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);

if (!isset($_GET['code'])){
  $auth_url = $client->getAuthenticationUrl(AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT, REDIRECT_URI);
header('Location: ' . $auth_url);
die('Redirect');
}
else {
  $params = array('code' => $_GET['code'], 'redirect_uri' => REDIRECT_URI);
  $response = $client->getAccessToken(TOKEN_ENDPOINT, 'authorization_code', $params);

  $access_tkn = $response['result']['access_token'];        
}
```

A quick way (not the safe one!) should be calling this page and get the result, but I cannot expose the page to the public, because everybody would be able to generate and use the token!!

Because of the redirection that happens when 'code' value is not yet available, I cannot even call this page via cUrl.

Any idea? I believe that a lot of people are facing my same problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you need to make a request to AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT. this is where the user will authenticate and grant access for your application to retrieve/use their personal info.

you will then be redirected to REDIRECT_URI, where you will retrieve the code from the querystring. you will use this code to make a request to the TOKEN_ENDPOINT to get tokens that you will use for each subsequent request for each user. yes, these tokens will be different for each user, and they will expire eventually. youll need to handle this expiration with a refresh token that you should also receive from the TOKEN_ENDPOINT.

Comment: Ok, this part was clear.
So I have not to generate the token by myself, but every user have to make a request the AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT and go on with the auth process? That's the part I was missing!

Now the problem is encrypt the call somehow... because every smart user can check the Chrome network tab and grab some dangerous information!

Comment: i dont think you need to encrypt the call. any information that the user could get would be their own information. right? or am i missing something...